# Basis of Eigenvectors for square root of $I_n$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

We know about a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, that $A^2 = I_n$. Does the matrix $A$ have a basis of eigenvectors?

Below are my thoughts about the problem.

Some of the roots are diagonal matrices. For such cases the basis exists.

But other square roots of $I_n$ can be antidiagonal, e.g. for $n=2$:
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right)$$

Here we have to manually check, that algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue equals its geometric multiplicity.

How can we do it for an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: $A^2 = I$ implies that $A^2-I=0$ or $(A+I)(A-I)=0$. So $1$ or $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Also the determinant of $A$ is $\pm1$. So the product of the eigenvalues is equal to $\pm1$. Not that this really helps your problem, just throwing some ideas out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general fact is:

> A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial splits into distinct linear factors.

Therefore, the answer is *yes*, because $X^2-1=(X-1)(X+1)$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is one of $X^2-1$, $X-1$, $X+1$, all of which split into distinct linear factors.

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know about it. Thank you!

Comment: @MaximBlumental. see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/minpolyandappns.pdf for a proof

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concrete answer.

Let $v \in V = \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $v=u+w$, where $u=(1/2)(v-Av)$ and $w=(1/2)(v+Av)$.

Now $u \in U = V_{-1}$ and $w \in W = V_{1}$, where $V_\lambda = \{ v \in V : Av = \lambda v \}$, a subspace of $V$.

Therefore, $V = U + W$. Since $U\cap W=0$, we have $V = U \oplus W$.

This means that $V$ has a basis of eigenvectors of $A$: join bases for $U$ and $W$.

Comment: The same idea works when $A$ satisfies a quadratic polynomial with real roots. Try it. For a cubic polynomial with real roots you need more work.